# How to partition a serial steps in sequence in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch, partition

I know the spring batch framework can partition a master step in order to run multiple slave steps in parrallel.

My requirement is to partition a serial steps in sequence (like a flow) to operate multiple tables, instead of only one step. I can only think of two alternatives on top of my head.

1. Create just one tasklet to assemble all the logics to update a serial tables.
2. Create the partition step for each step in the flow.

Ideally, I would like spring batch supports this function out of box. Please shed some light what is the best way to achieve the goal.

### An example is much appreciated.

Update: I did some google search and found that I may partition the flow using FlowStep as below. Is this right approach to do it?

```
public Step partiotionStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("partiotionStep")
            .partitioner("slaveStep", partitioner())
            .step(new FlowStep(flow()))
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();

 public Flow flow() {
    return new FlowBuilder<Flow>("flow")
            .start(step1())
            .next(step2())
            .next(step3())
            .build();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "partition a serial steps in sequence"? You can have multiple steps running in sequence and each one of them is a partitioned step. Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, or I can use FlowStep to partition multiple steps as a flow. Please see the updated question. Is it preferrable to do so?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. See my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a job with multiple steps in sequence, each step being a partitioned step:

```
public Job job() {
    return jobBuilderFactory("job")
            .start(step1()) // step1 is a partitioned step
            .next(step2()) // step2 is also a partitioned step
            .build();
}
```

You can find a similar question with an example in my answer here: [Is it possible to combine partition and parallel steps in spring batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232490/is-it-possible-to-combine-partition-and-parallel-steps-in-spring-batch/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your example. One question for your example, if both step1 and step2 use the same input values, how to share the execution context between  step1 and step2? Or step1 and step2 have to invoke the same partitioner() call back to feed the same input values respectively? @Mahmoud Ben Hassine

Comment: Another question for partitioned step, say I have 3 slave steps (i.e., slaveStep1, slaveStep2 and slaveStep3) for step1, if  slaveStep1 fails and slaveStep2/slaveStep3 succeed, will slaveStep1 be marked as failed, but step1 continue the execution, and step2 will be triggered. Or step1 will fail and the job execution is stopped. @Mahmoud Ben Hassine

Comment: if one of the worker steps fail, the partitioned master step will fail. Now since step1 and step2 are defined to run in sequence, if step1 fails, then the job will fail too and step2 will not be executed.